# Cant see column data in my java table, problem

Tags: java

Hello im trying to make my first table in java but there is information who is not being displayed properly. I was researching because at the begining the first error was the table doesnt show the column names so i added a JScrollPane and now the table totally dissapear.

Here is the code:

```
private JTable table;
private String [][] datosFila= {
        {"A1","A2","A3"},
        {"B1","B2","B3"},
        {"C1","C2","C3"}};
private String [] columnas= {"Prueba1","Prueba2","Prueba3"};


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SelectProfile window = new SelectProfile();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public SelectProfile( ) {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 862, 498);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("SELECCIONE PERFIL USUARIO");
    lblNewLabel.setToolTipText("");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(115, 23, 755, 110);
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 41));
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    table = new JTable(datosFila,columnas);
    table.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    table.setShowGrid(false);

    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
    JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(js);

    table.setBounds(215, 146, 345, 259);
```

Thanks anticipated, best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of issues there.

1. Setting the LayoutManager to null is causing some weird behaviour. Taking it out at least lets elements show up. 
   You can just remove that line if you like, but I would recommend using a basic LayoutManager (i.e. the FlowLayout)
2. You are adding the JTable to both your JFrame and the JScrollPane. You should only be adding it to the scroll pane.

I tested the following code and I thing it does what you want:

```
    public SelectProfile() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 862, 498);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(862, 498));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("SELECCIONE PERFIL USUARIO");
        lblNewLabel.setToolTipText("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(115, 23, 755, 110);
        lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 41));
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        table = new JTable(datosFila,columnas);
        table.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setBounds(215, 146, 345, 259);

        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(table);
        js.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,50));
        frame.getContentPane().add(js);

        frame.pack();
    }
```

It should noted that I have set the preferred size of the scroll pane to very small so you can see that the scroll pane is working. You will likely want to either remove that line of increase the size.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the content in the contentpane every time you do a  frame.getContentPane().add();

You should read Oraclale's tutorial about layout managers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html